# find all $k$ so that eventually $a_n = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, recurrence-relations

> Define the sequences $a_n,b_n,c_n$ as follows. $a_0=k, b_0=4,c_0=1.$ If $a_n$ is even, $a_{n+1} = a_n/2, b_{n+1} = 2b_n, c_{n+1} = c_n$. If $a_n$ is odd, $a_{n+1} = a_n - b_n/2-c_n, b_{n+1} = b_n, c_{n+1}=b_n+c_n$. Find the number of positive integers $k < 1995$ so that some $a_n=0$.

In the solution below, I was wondering if someone could explain why the $x_0$ corresponding to $(y,z)$ is greater than the $x_0$ corresponding to $y',z'$ if $y > y'$ or if $y = y'$ and $z > z'$? Obviously the initial corresponding value for $(y,z)$ is $y/2 + z$, which is larger than $y'/2 + z'$ in either case. But even though the first component of each tuple increases every time, it's not clear how fast these components increase relative to each other after each step (e.g. for the triples $(128,1)$ and $(64,61)$, the first four values of the first components are respectively $130,260,520,1040$ and $186,231,462,483$ and it doesn't seem obvious to prove that the final result for $(64,61)$ will be smaller than that for $(128,1)$).

[image]